# With TextInput widgets from Kivy or KivyMD, I am unable to move the cursor with the arrows on my keyboard (from the numeric pad)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I am testing Kivy on a Windows 10 computer. When I click in a TextInput widget, I can type and move the cursor using the 'inverted-T' arrows from my keyboard, but not from the arrows on my numeric pad (with NumLock=Off) which I use all the time.  Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of John Anderson, I was able to find a complete solution by remapping the numpad keys to regular keys when numlock is off:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField

numpad_map = dict(
        numpad1=(279, 'end'     ),      #257
        numpad2=(274, 'down'    ),      #258
        numpad3=(281, 'pagedown'),      #259
        numpad4=(276, 'left'    ),      #260
        numpad6=(275, 'right'   ),      #262
        numpad7=(278, 'home'    ),      #263
        numpad8=(273, 'up'      ),      #264
        numpad9=(280, 'pageup'  ),      #265
        numpaddecimal=(127, 'delete'),  #266
    )

def fix_numpad(keycode, modifiers):
    """This function actually remap numpad arrows to regular arrows if numlock is off"""
    keynum, keylbl = keycode
    if 'numlock' not in modifiers and keylbl in numpad_map:
        keycode = numpad_map[keylbl]
    return keycode

class TextInput2(TextInput):
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        keycode = fix_numpad(keycode, modifiers)
        return super().keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)

class MDTextField2(MDTextField):
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        keycode = fix_numpad(keycode, modifiers)
        return super().keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_normal

    TextInput2:

    MDTextField2:

"""

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

**EDIT:** Digging further in the source code, I realized that MDTextField has many subclasses and inherits from FixedHintTextInput, which inherits from TextInput.  **So I found a universal way of patching TextInput.**  I am not sure this is the most robust solution, but I find it somewhat elegant because it fixes the behaviour of all widgets without having to alter the class names in our layout (until a the kivy source code is actually patched).  Here is the code:

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivymd.app import MDApp

def wrap_class_function(class_type, fn_attr_name, fn_wrapper_maker):
    """Replaces a method at the Class-level (class function) so that it affects
    all instance methods (current and future, including subclasses)"""
    old_fn = getattr(class_type, fn_attr_name)    # Get original class function
    new_fn = fn_wrapper_maker(old_fn)             # Create new wrapper around it
    new_fn.__name__ = fn_attr_name                # Set the __name__ of wrapper (so bindings still work)
    setattr(class_type, fn_attr_name, new_fn)     # Replace old function with new one

def keyboard_on_key_down_wrapper_maker(original_fn):
    """Creates a wrapper function that applies the numpad patch, to be used
    directly on TextInput base class (to fix all subclasses)"""
    numpad_map = dict(
            numpad1=(279, 'end'     ),      #257
            numpad2=(274, 'down'    ),      #258
            numpad3=(281, 'pagedown'),      #259
            numpad4=(276, 'left'    ),      #260
            numpad6=(275, 'right'   ),      #262
            numpad7=(278, 'home'    ),      #263
            numpad8=(273, 'up'      ),      #264
            numpad9=(280, 'pageup'  ),      #265
            numpaddecimal=(127, 'delete'),  #266
        )
    def keyboard_on_key_down_wrapper(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        key, key_str = keycode
        if 'numlock' not in modifiers and key_str in numpad_map:
            keycode = numpad_map[key_str]
        return original_fn(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers)
    return keyboard_on_key_down_wrapper

wrap_class_function(TextInput, 'keyboard_on_key_down', keyboard_on_key_down_wrapper_maker)

KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.bg_normal

    TextInput:

    MDTextField:  # This widget inherits TextInput patch
"""

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

Test().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a class that extends `TextInput` and uses the numeric pad arrows. Here is an example:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    def keyboard_on_key_down(self, window, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if 'numlock' not in modifiers:
            if keycode[0] == 264: # up arrow
                self.do_cursor_movement('cursor_up')
            elif keycode[0] == 262:  # right arrow
                self.do_cursor_movement('cursor_right')
            elif keycode[0] == 258:  # down arrow
                self.do_cursor_movement('cursor_down')
            elif keycode[0] == 260:  # left arrow
                self.do_cursor_movement('cursor_left')
        return super(MyTextInput, self).keyboard_on_key_down(window, keycode, text, modifiers)
```

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your answer. I am successfully able to use the numpad arrows, but the inverted-T arrows no longer work.  Also I tried the same trick on an MDTextField but the whole widget disappears instead (any idea why).  Thanks.

Comment: Update: Your solution works well for an MDTextField (with both arrow sets).  In my .kv file,  had a '<-MDTextField>' block that the subclass does not like and made it disappear.  However for a regular TextInput, the inverted-T arrows still do not work.

Comment: I have no idea why you see that behavior. My code only adds behavior for the number pad and it always passes all pressed keys to the normal processing code, so I don't understand why it would affect anything else. Would you add a `print(keycode)` line as the first line in the `keyboard_on_key_down()` method above, and let me know what it prints when you press the 'inverted-T' arrows?

Comment: I removed the arguments of super() and it worked.  Then I realized I was also missing combined key strokes (like CTRL-LEFT to jump a word).  So with your help and printing the keycode I was able to fix everything. I will post my solution.